# Sqlite android add character field

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am having a problem with my `sqlite` query. I have table like this

If table name = "**A**" , and having field table with name "**value_A**"

```
**value_A** = "1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6"
```

and I run 2 different queries:

```
query_1 = SELECT  * FROM A WHERE value_A LIKE '%- 1 % 2 -%'

query_2 = SELECT  * FROM A WHERE ('B '+value_A+' B') LIKE '%- 1 % 2 -%'

query_2 is , i want add character "B  " and " B" each value_A
```

query_1 gives a result, but query_2 gives no result , but I want query_2 to return a result as well.

Comment: value_A be "B 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 B" from "1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6" ?

Comment: query_1 returns no result. The pattern `- 1` doesn't appear anywhere in the `value_A` you mentioned. Same goes for query_2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the string concatenation operator which is "||".

So in your case it would be something like:

```
SELECT 'B ' || value_A || ' B' FROM A WHERE value_A LIKE '%1 % 2 -%'
```

That is, if I understood your question right in that you want your results to contain the added trailing and ending 'B'.  But I agree the question could use some more clarity.